# Dimension of a subspace of $R^2$ respectively $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

"What is the dimension of the following subspace of $R^2$ respectively $R^3$?

Span { \begin{pmatrix}-6\\ 12\\ -14\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1\\ -4\\ 4\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}12\\ 12\\ -10\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 2\\ -3\end{pmatrix}}"

I thought the dimension was just how many vectors there were in the subspace. So, for this one, would it be 4? Even if this one is 4, I see that their are other subspaces that have dimensions that are not equivalent to the number of vectors in the subspace. So, in general, how exactly would we calculate the dimension of a subspace if not by counting the number of vectors?

Any help?

Comment: Isn't the dimension of a vector space the total number of elements in its basis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of a vector space given by a span, is *atmost* the number of vectors given in the span, and *atmost* the dimension of each vector. Hence, in this case, we see that the dimension cannot exceed three, since each of the vectors is three dimensional.

Now, the following is the way to find the dimension of the subspace : We know that any element of the subspace is of the form $w(-6,12,-14) +x(-1,-4,4) + y(12,12,-10) + z(-4,2,-3)$, where $w,x,y,z$ are real numbers.

Adding up, we see that any such vector is of the form: $$(a,b,c) = (-6w-x+12y-4z,12w-4x+12y+2z,-14w + 4x-10y-3z)$$

Now, how many "linear relations" exist between $a,b,c$? That is, suppose I fix $a$ and $b$. Does this end up fixing the value of $c$? With the above question as motivation, let us call a set of variables as "maximally free", if fixing these variables, leads to all the other variables getting fixed, but fixing a strictly smaller subset does not lead to all variables being fixed.

The size of any "maximally free" set of variables ends up being the dimension of the desired space. I can explain this if you like, but if we skip it, we will still be okay.

To do this, we write down the equations for $a,b,c$, and see if any of $w,x,y,z$ can be eliminated by addition/subtraction:
$$
a = -6w-x+12y-4z \\
b = 12w-4x+12y+2z \\c = -14w+4x-10y-3z
$$

If you do this, we would get that $b,c$ is a maximally free set. It turns out that $a = \frac{19b}{4} + \frac{9c}{2}$, so fixing $b,c$ actually fixes $a$. So the dimension of the given space is $2$.

---

This process can also be done using matrices : write down the above vectors as an augmented matrix and try to obtain as many rows or columns of zeros by doing elementary row and column operations. The number of non-zero rows/columns is then the desired dimension.

We show the result after row reduction.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-6 & -1 & 12 & -4 \\
12 & -4 & 12 & 2 \\
-14 & 4 & -10 & -3
\end{pmatrix}
\to \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0.5 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence, the dimension of the space, is the number of rows which are not all zero, which is two.

Answer (score -1):

Please improve the writing. You mean that is a subspace of R^3.
To solve your cuestion, first recall that the dimension of a subspace of R^3 is lower or equal than 3. So, under no curcumstance your space has dimensión 4.   To solve that, you must find a linear independent subset, the amount of lineary independent vectors gives you the dimension